# "Answers For ALL" Day - Register now!

Tags: discussion, events, unanswered-questions

**[Chatroom schedule for "You are here"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule)**

An event at the end of next week.  It will coincide with the last few days before Christmas, people hopefully have time to spend a few minutes / hours answering questions.

This event has three goals:

1. To reduce unanswered questions to 0
2. To increase the number of answers per question to 2.3. (Currently about 2.2).
3. The obvious - to drive more traffic as a result of better quality answers, more information and more interaction!

[**REGISTER NOW!**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule)

Join us in the chat room that day, to help each other out, and to increase the detail, answers and information on Travel.SE!

Comment: Some days I wonder why I get out of bed ;) Fixed.

Comment: That's a good idea. Does anybody of you know how to find questions that have only one answer? I already asked this on MSO, but no answer so far.

Comment: only http://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A1&submit=search which shows answers of 1 OR more. Not specificly 1 tho :(

Comment: Yes that's the problem that it is a minimum. I want it to be a maximum.

Comment: Once the site is out of beta, it should be possible to set up an "exactly one answer" custom query on StackExchange Data Explorer. http://data.stackexchange.com/  Until then, I think we're stuck with the answers:1 as a minimum.

Comment: For example, here's one I whipped together for the Bicycles site:  http://data.stackexchange.com/bicycles/q/121971/second-opinion-needed